# Hudson Free Temp Space location

Tags: jenkins, hudson, diskspace, temp

I have just installed Hudson on a Weblogic server and I am having issues with the nodes going off line due to the Free Temp Space falling below the 1gig threshold. Now I have checked my /tmp folder (thinking Hudson uses that) but it is sitting at 10gigs free.

Would anybody be able to point me to the folder Hudson uses? Also I am using a SunOS box.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the web interface go to the node's SystemInfo page (http://hudsonserver/systemInfo)and it will tell you what temp folder it is using. Look for  "java.io.tmpdir" on that page.

Comment: @CiscolPPhone you can pass the following param when starting Hudson: -DHUDSON_HOME=/path/path/hudson

Answer (score 5):

Change it with the configuration page of the node, in the "Launch method" section, click "Advanced", "JVM Options" setting:

Example:

> -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Bill's answer, you can change this through the registry.

- **Key:** HKLM\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat6\Parameters\Java
- **Value:** Options (look for java.io.tmpdir)